# Pandas data structure for 2-D Complex Time Series Data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm newish to python and pandas and am struggling with the right approach to a structure for my data.  Here is a summary of a single observation of my data:

1. I have a time stamp of collection (collection times may not be periodic)
2. The observation is a vector of complex data (real and imaginary parts)
3. The length of the vector will not be the same for each collection
4. Each vector is a set of observations over a short time period
5. The time spacing between each element in the vector can change from one observation to the next
6. Each observation contains meta data, the values of the meta data can change but the structure ("keys") will stay the same

Each observation looks like it could be a Series object. Yet, since the length of each observation vector is not consistent from one collection time to the next, it seems difficult to use DataFrames.

Any good ideas? Is this perfect for Panels? I do not have an example I can put up on this board unfortunately.

**Update**

Some examples of what might be done with the data:

1. Statistics of data per observation (independent of other observations)
2. Statistics of data on groups of observation (grouped by data stored in the meta data)
3. Additional processing on groups of observation (e.g., FFT) (grouped by data stored in meta data)

The output of the above examples would be sent to a "map" or "reduce" type function.

Comment: you need to give an example of what you are going to do with the data; e.g what operations / indexing etc

Comment: Hopefully made a useful update, indexing should be done by the time stamp, the varying size of the observation vector and sample spacing within the vector are my major headaches.  Maybe subclass DataFrame?

Comment: start simple and put your data in a frame; it handles complex data.

Comment: Yeah, currently I'm just putting the vector into one column. But to process a group of n observations I have to use np.vstack(df.data.iloc[:n].values), seems a bit verbose

Comment: you can try a panel; but w/o seeing a real example hard to tell